# proper way to convert promise with resolve & reject to async function (puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, puppeteer

so im new to async functions and promises ,  imagine a promiselike this   (pleas ignore syntax errors)

```
await new Promise(async (resolve, reject ) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://example.com').catch( ()=>reject('ERROR -> LINK 1 TIMEOUT '));
    // INSERT USERNAME AND PASSWORD 
    await page.$eval('form', form => form.submit()).catch( ()=>reject('ERROR -> FORM SUBMIT ERROR '));

        if( await page.$("#username"))
        {

            reject(" ERROR -> LOGIN FAILED !!!!!!!!!!!!!! ");
        }




    await page.waitForSelector('#xxx').catch( ()=>reject('ERROR -> WAITING FOR ELEMENT TIMEOUT '));

    var scraped_data = // dop some page evaluate and scrap data;

    resolve(scraped_data);

}).then(function(scraped_data){

    await page.close();
    console.log('all done');
    insert_data_in_databas(scraped_data);

})
.catch(function(error){

    console.log(' tab failed : ');
    console.log(error);
});
```

i want to convert this to a async function  ... what is proper way to do this ? should i just put all of them in a try/catch block like

```
async function do_stuff(){

    try {
        const page    = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 1100});
        await page.goto( 'https://example.com'  );
        // INSERT USERNAME AND PASSWORD 
        await page.$eval('form', form => form.submit());
        await page.waitForSelector('#xxx');
        var scraped_data = // dop some page evaluate and scrap data;
        await page.close();
        console.log('all done');
        insert_data_in_databas(scraped_data);    
    }
    catch (e) {
        await page.close();
        console.log('error');
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

how can i reject when there is a error so the rest of the code wouldnt execute ? can i have custom error text in catche block like

```
ERROR -> FORM SUBMIT ERROR
```

how should i to this

```
  if( await page.$("#username"))
        {

            reject(" ERROR -> LOGIN FAILED !!!!!!!!!!!!!! ");
        }
```

which is not an actual error (i mean its not code error) in try/catche ?

------------------------------------------ edit --------------------

i tried

```
async function open_tab(){

    try {
        const page    = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 1100});
        await page.goto( 'https://google.com'  );
        await page.waitForSelector('#xxx').catch(()=> { throw new Error('ERROR -> LOGIN FAILED')});
        await page.close();
        console.log('all done');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(e);
        await page.close();

    }
}
```

its almost working but i cant close the tab in the catch block i get

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: page is not defined
```

and the tab remains open which is not ideal

Comment: The first snippet is promise construction antipattern. Puppeteer is promise-based. No promises should be created if there are existing ones. *how should i to this* - likely `throw new Error('ERROR ->...')`. Do you have problems with second snippet besides that?

Comment: @estus thanx i dont want to create a promise inside async function ... i just want to knwo the proper way to rewrite it to async function ... second snipet is my attempt to rewrite the promise with async function

Comment: I added the answer for clarification. Do you have other concerns in this function besides that?

Comment: "*how can i reject when there is a error so the rest of the code wouldnt execute*" - that's exactly what your second code is doing (when a promise is rejected the `await` expression throws an exception and jumps to the `catch` clause) and what your first code is failing to do (it just continues after you called `reject()`).

Comment: "*ReferenceError: page is not defined*" - well you will need to put the `const page = await browser.newPage();` outside of the `try` block.

Comment: @Bergi thank you , about the first snipet  i tough reject would stop promise execution was i wrong ?

Comment: @max It would prevent the `new Promise` from being rejected/resolved otherwise. No, it's just a function call, it does not stop anything like a `return` or `throw` keyword would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no `new Promise` because a promise already exists and can be chained.

If resulting promise should be rejected in `async` function, it is:

```
if (await page.$("#username")) {
   throw new Error('ERROR -> LOGIN FAILED');
}
```

It should be

```
let page;
try {
    page    = await browser.newPage();
```

instead of

```
try {
    const page    = await browser.newPage();
```

Comment: ok thanx , so i  just put all of the code in try/cathc and do custom errors like 

  await page.$eval('form', form => form.submit()).catche( ()=>  throw new Error('ERROR -> FORM FAILED'););

Answer (score 1):

// Best solution for error handling in puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const param_puppeteer = {
  args: [
    "--incognito",
    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "--window-size=1920,1080",
    "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas",
    "--disable-gpu",

    // '--unlimited-storage',
    // '--no-startup-window',
    // '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    // '--disable-crash-reporter',
    // '--disable-breakpad'
  ],
  headless: false,
};

async function start() {
  return puppeteer
    .launch(param_puppeteer)
    .then(async (browser) => {
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      return await task(page)
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        .finally(() => browser.close());
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

async function task(page) {
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 1100 });
  await page.goto("https://google.com");
  await page.waitForSelector("#hplogo");
  let exist = await page.$("#hplogo").then((res) => !!res);
  if (exist) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("success"));
  } else {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject("failed"));
  }
}

start();
```

Comment: retry task  :  function task(page,index) { ... if(index<totalIndex)  task(page,index+1)

Comment: Perhaps add some comments to your code to make it easier to read.